# jssc SerialPortList in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Eclipse IDE. with jssc-0.9.0 release and I have correctly added jssc.jar to Referenced Libraries. But when I run it, it's always terminated. 
Says "Main[Java Application]/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java"
this is my code

```
import jssc.SerialPortList;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
        for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
            System.out.println(portNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar problem, so I examined the jssc code and found out that in linux the SerialPortList.getPortNames() parses dmesg output for port names starting with 'ttyS' or 'ttyUSB' - but my only serial device was on ttyACM0 and of course the getPortNames function couldn't find it... You may as well check if the jssc's linux native library (libjSSC-0.9_x86.so) was extracted from jssc.jar to ~/.jssc/linux/ when you ran your code...

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and in my humble opinion the answer is not correct - at least not with version 2.8.0 of jssc.

In my case the Port list was empty, because Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 in my case) does not permit any user to use Serial-Ports - thats why the list was empty. So I executed the following command to add my user to the usergroup that is allowed to use serial ports:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout tim
```

I needed to logout and login again to the system in order to be recognized as a member of that group by the system - but after that I got the following line when I execute the snippet above:

```
/dev/ttyACM0
```

It now contains the only configured serial port that my user is allowed to see due to rights.